# PHP Fatal Error not logging in error log

Tags: php, apache, shutdown, error-log

We are using LAMP Architecture. PHP Shutdown function is capturing some fatal errors. But these fatal errors are not logged in apache error_log files. We have used two versions of PHP. Both the versions are functioning similarly. Versions: php-5.2.17 and php-5.3.14

Comment: What do you mean by `php shutdown` - what logging levels do you have configured in your php.ini and most importantly what error are you expecting

Comment: enable the error log file in php.ini and see if that helps.

Comment: It is register_shutdown_function in PHP. We have error_reporting=E_ALL in our /etc/php.ini